# fieldset and legend tags - should I use them and in what contexts?

Tags: html, accessibility, semantic-markup, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

I went to a talk back in 2008 by a blind lady who said not to use the fieldset and legend tags when you have more than a few fields because they were a nuisance as screen readers (Jaws in her case) read the legend out before every field label.

Is this the case anymore? I have seen that their contexts are both with related fields and when you have checkboxes/radio inputs. **If you have related checkbox fields would you nest the fieldset tags or would you just use it for one of those contexts?** I also note that this is probably an issue with the AT software.

Calling all a11y experts and screen reader users/testers.
I am under the assumption that Jaws is still the most widely used SR.

Comment: With the rise of iOS, JAWS may have been overtaken by VoiceOver.

Comment: [WCAG 2.0 - H71: Providing a description for groups of form controls using fieldset and legend elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H71.html)

Answer (score 2):

This annual survey is the best data that exists for screen reader use:

http://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey5/#primary

As you can see, JAWS is still 50% and the clear leader.

That having been said, you MUST provide a group of inputs that logically belong together a common group label. This is particularly important for radio buttons and checkboxes. Each screen reader announces these differently and you cannot control this unless you use ARIA markup for the group labels. However `<fieldset>` and `<legend>` are still the preferred mechanism.

Examples of how to do this can be found here: http://dylanb.github.io/group_labels.html

Comment: Preferred mechanism for related fields OR radio/checkbox groups OR both? If both how would you nest them? Please could you provide an example?

Comment: For example if I had Address fields and one of them was a group of radio buttons that had In USA, In Europe, Other in the middle of the Address fields

Comment: the techniques on the page above can be expanded to support groups within groups - however I would try to avoid this

Comment: Ok so i'm assuming to avoid the outer fieldset wrapper then as the radio groups would be more important. Views?

Comment: It depends. You could use a heading instead. It really depends on the context

Answer (score 1):

I've just found the answer from Bim who I was referring to in the question, despite being 8 years ago on [Paciello Group's Blog](http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2007/11/fieldsets-legends-and-screen-readers/). She says:

> One thing to emphasise is that nesting FIELDSET elements is also OK,
>   and is often necessary to avoid confusion.

Sounds like that is the right way to go unless things have changed since then in ATs. I know upgrading Jaws versions moves slow as it is so expensive to buy.

I'll test at soon using Voiceover.